# What do These Names Have in Common?

Tags: word, word-property, connections-puzzle

What verb do these four names have in common?

**Copenhagen

Danny

Roger

Tina**

Clues:

> If you get stumped on Tina, don't worry. It's a lesser known reference, and if you have a solution for the other three names, then Tina will probably fit in!

> Danny and Roger are both first names of celebrities.

> Danny is the pseudonym of a Lebanese-American actor.

> Roger was in an English rock band.

> Copenhagen is a brand name.

Comment: Hi Nilster! We usually don't encourage posting this many hints to start. Puzzles are supposed to be solvable without any hints. If you feel the hints are needed, just put them as part of the puzzle itself.

Comment: Is Tina a reference to a person like Danny and Roger?

Comment: Tina is not a person :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The all have the verb spit in common

> Copenhagen is a smokeless tobacco brand which is not smoked but chewed and spat. It is also known as spit tobacco.

> Danny Thomas is an actor and is well known for the 'Spit take'.

> The Bassist Roger Waters of Pink floyd was known to spit on a fan in Montreal 1977.

> Tina is a pet Llama in Napoleon Dynamite 2004 and they are known to spit.

Comment: Yay! You got the Tina reference!

Answer (score 2):

**Partial Answer**

Perhaps it is:

> Smoke

> [Copenhagen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_(tobacco)) is a type of smokeless tobacco

> [Danny Thomas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Thomas) is Lebanese-American actor famous for (among other things) founding [St. Jude's Hospital](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Jude_Children%27s_Research_Hospital) which is known for fighting cancer--which is sometimes thought to be caused by smoking

> [Roger Daltrey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Daltrey) is an English rock musician famous for his allergy to smoke.

My biggest problem, however, is that I don't have the faintest idea how Tina fits into this, hence why this is a partial answer.

Comment: Good guess! rot13(Lbh jrer evtug nobhg Qnaal Gubznf, ohg ybbx zber vagb uvf npgvat pnerre. Erzrzore, gur nafjre vf n ireo- Pbcrauntra vf ersreevat gb gur fzbxryrff gbonppb oenaq, fb guvax nobhg jung lbh qb jvgu vg. Ynfgyl, Ebtre Qnygerl vfa'g pbeerpg. Guvf Ebtre vf n onffvfg jub qvq fbzrguvat cerggl zrzbenoyr qhevat n gbhe va gur 70'f. Nf sbe Gvan, fur'f n crg va n zbivr sebz 2004!)